# Add optional parameter to Android Kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created an extension of `DialogFragment()`:

```
class AlertDialogFragment(context: Context, 
                          val positiveButtonText: String, 
                          val positiveButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,
                          val negativeButtonText: String, 
                          val negativeButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  
                          neutralButtonText: String, 
                          neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener
                          ) : DialogFragment() {
```

however I want the last 2 parameters to be optional.

How can I achieve this?

I can't set `neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener = null` because `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` is a non null type.

Comment: Try placing **?** as Null-Coalescing operator `neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null`, this way your variable becomes **nullable**. So, make sure you don't end up having **NPE**.

Comment: You can assign default listener for that but you can not assign null there, Or else you can create the same method with rest of last two params

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this out

```
class AlertDialogFragment(  
    context: Context,  
    val positiveButtonText: String,  
    val positiveButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  
    val negativeButtonText: String,  
    val negativeButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  
    neutralButtonText: String = "",  
    neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener ?= null
) : DialogFragment() { }
```

Answer (score 19):

Default parameters to the rescue.

```
class AlertDialogFragment(
    context: Context,
    val positiveButtonText: String,
    val positiveButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,
    val negativeButtonText: String,
    val negativeButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener, 
    neutralButtonText: String = "",
    neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener = OnClickListener {}
) : DialogFragment()
```

Basically, Kotlin will generate multiple methods, for each combination of parameters possible.

If could also be better to include `@JvmOverload` annotation on the constructor to allow the same thing in Java.

Comment: "@JvmOverloads not @JvmOverload"

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
class AlertDialogFragment(
    context: Context,  
    val positiveButtonText: String,  
    val positiveButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  
    val negativeButtonText: String,  
    val negativeButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  
    neutralButtonText: String = "",  
    neutralButtonListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener = OnClickListener {}  
) : DialogFragment() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you would provide no-op or null-value implementations like

```
neutralButtonText: String = ""
neutralButtonListener: OnClickListener = OnClickListener {}
```

But in your use-case you **must not** use constructor parameters at all!

Fragments can be recreated from the system and require a default constructor.

You need to [communicate with the `activity` or `parentFragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity) by letting these implement the interface you require.

Comment: How do I reuse the fragment then if I want to use it for multiple instances?

Comment: You could configure it from an `activity` or `parentFragment`. Or you make the fragment abstract and configure it with the actual implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call kotlin function from Java file which has default arguments

Then use this annotation for your kotlin function

```
@JvmOverloads
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple...

For class use

```
class MyClass(param1: Int, param2: Boolean) {
    constructor(param1: Int) : this(param1, true)
    constructor(param2: Boolean) : this(10, param2)
}
```

and for functions

```
@JvmOverloads
fun yourMethod(param1: Int, param2: Boolean = true) {
   // ... define your method
}
```

Now you can call this method any of the below

`yourMethod(1)`

`yourMethod(1, true)`

`yourMethod(param1 = 1, param2 = false)` etc.,

Answer (score 0):

We can add the optional paramater like below. z is optional here

```
  fun main() {
 add(5,6,7)
```

}

```
fun add(x:Int,y:Int,z:Int?=0){
    if(z!=null && z>0)
    println(x+y+z)
    else
    println(x+y)
}
```